# Using jQuery to change the order of Select Options not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a friend that helped me code this as I am unable to get it working correctly. I am trying to edit the order of the Select list items as I am unable to edit the list manually because the list is populated within a Wordpress plugin called SellMedia. The code supplied currently works but when you click on the dropdown list it works, then if you click off and back on it change the order.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

```
$(document).on('click','#sell_media_item_size',function(){

    $("#sell_media_item_size option").slice(1, 19).each(function () {
      var options = $('#sell_media_item_size option');

      $(this).insertAfter($(options[0]));
    });
});
```

Example here - https://jsfiddle.net/7bbxd42b/5/

Comment: Note, use eq(0) instead of [0] so you don't have to rewrap the dom element

Comment: So is the issue that you only want it to happen once?

Comment: Maybe you would use the 'change' event on the selectbox.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar & Franco I tried that and didn't change anything. The reason it is on click is because the element isn't visible on the page until the popup is created by the plugin so by putting on click it enables the jQuery to work. Also i just want it to change the the correct order on clicking on the dropdown menu. See the Jsfiddle or example but the code renders differently on my site.

Comment: I can't understand, Why you need to order the items every time you click open the drop down? isn't it enough to order it once when data is populating?

Answer (score 0):

You should order only once. You can use a flag on the global level to check that you have already ordered the entries:

```
var ordered = false;
$(document).on('click','#sell_media_item_size',function(){

    if (!ordered) {
        $("#sell_media_item_size option").slice(1, 19).each(function () {
            var options = $('#sell_media_item_size option');
            $(this).insertAfter($(options[0]));
        });
        ordered = true; 
    }
});
```

It would be even better, if you could check it some other way, so you would not need the global flag.

**Update:** I just found out, you can use `.one()` instead of `.on()` to bind the click event. So the handler will be fired only once.

Comment: I have tried this but still no luck. I have added a page with the dropdown on so you can see it rendering on my site. [Website Link](http://ryankerswell.co.uk/photography/test/). It does populate but when you come off and load another product it just resets it self.

Comment: Well, in your fiddle it seems to solve the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ruvrhyr0/ Where is the dropdown on your website?

Comment: Go to this link [CLICK HERE](http://ryankerswell.co.uk/photography/test) and click on the purchase button to load the dropdown menus in a popout window to see the results.